# Ladybug how to install in Zend Framework 2 -ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

[Ladybug](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug) provides an easy and extensible var_dump / print_r replacement for PHP 5.3+ projects. Any PHP variable, object or resource can be dumped to beautiful representation.

How do you install this for Zend Framework 2?

Comment: Just use composer... `composer require raulfraile/ladybug`

Answer (score 1):

There is [an installation guide inside the documentation](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug/blob/master/doc/installation.md) that suggests using composer:

> ### Installation
>
> The recommended way to install Ladybug is through Composer.
>
> Download the composer binary:
>
> ```
> wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
> # or
> curl -O http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
> ```
>
> Now, install Ladybug with Composer:
>
> ```
> composer.phar require raulfraile/ladybug
> ```

So maybe you could simply try that?